# socket.io emit only working for one user?

Tags: reactjs, websocket, socket.io

I'm trying to implement socket.io into a react application. I've followed the documentation however I am struggling to get 'two browser windows' or 'emulating two devices' to communicate with each other.

The implementation that I have is working, however when I emit a change to the server, it is only being picked up on the window or device that made the change, and the other clients don't see the emit.

Can anyone please advise where I am going wrong, and how I can get the changes to be picked up by the other clients?

**server.js**

```
const server = require("http").createServer();
const io = require("socket.io")(server, {
    cors: {
        origin: "*"
    }
});

io.on('connection', socket => {
    console.log('User Connected:' + socket.id);

    socket.on('child-login', (data) => {
        console.log(data);
        console.log(socket.id);
        socket.emit('child-login', data);
    })

});

server.listen(3001, () => {
    console.log('Server Running....')
});
```

**react component js**

```
import api from "../utilities/api";
import { useState } from "react";

import { io } from 'socket.io-client';

const socket = io('http://localhost:3001');

socket.on('child-login', (data) => {
    document.querySelector('.js-last-login').innerHTML = data;
});

function Dashboard() {

    const loginChild = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        let self = e.target;
        socket.emit('child-login', e.target.innerHTML);
    }

    return (
       <div>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a onClick={loginChild}>Walter Melon</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a onClick={loginChild}>Teri Dactyl</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
           <h1 className="js-last-login"></h1>
       </div>
    );
}

export default Dashboard;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case - just use

```
io.emit('child-login', data)
```

instead of

```
socket.emit('child-login', data);
```

which emits event only to the 'source' socket.

Here you can read more about the [broadcasting](https://socket.io/docs/v3/broadcasting-events/).